# I want to disable/enable keyboard through C code but I am getting segmenation fault

Tags: c, io

```
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{    
    iopl(5);//permission
    outb(0Xf5,0X64);//writting to port to disable
    printf("keyboard disabled");
    sleep(1000);
    printf("keyboard enabled");
    outb(0Xf4,0X64);
}
```

Getting segmenation fault while disabling/enabling code but I am not getting where I am wrong. Please check!

Comment: Quote: "outb() and friends are hardware-specific". ([Source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inl.2.html)). What is your hardware then?

Comment: Meanwhile, when inserting debug print to catch a segmentation fault, note that `stdout` is buffered, so chances are high that you will not see output after at least a newline is printed (and will not see it ever if program will crash before buffer is flushed), so use something like `fprintf(stderr, "keyboard disabled\n")` -- `stderr` is unbuffered by default. AFAIK `stdout` is by default line-buffered when connected to a terminal (not redirected to file), so adding `\n` at the end of your message may suffice, but I prefer just use `stderr` for debug printing when possible.

Comment: You should check the return value of `iopl` to see if it was successful, or if it perhaps says that `5` isn't a proper value for a 2-bit privilege level. https://linux.die.net/man/2/iopl

Comment: What operating system are you using? The thing you are trying is quite OS dependant....

Comment: i am using linux mint